# Get values according to array

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

```
I have one table, pricing_criteria_details in which there is criteria stored in comma separated format. 

criteria id 1 => Customer
criteria id 2 => Material
criteria id 3 => Material Group

For example, criteria => 1,2
             criteria => 1,3

    enter code here
```

Now I have another table, pricing_values, in which values of criteria are stored in comma separated format.

For example, values => 3,40 (Customer3, Material40)
values => 4,25 (Customer4, Materialgroup25)

```
Now I want to get this data on single screen.

If it is 1,2 and 3,40 
then how will I know that for 1 is customer and customer3 is assigned
And if it is 2 that is for material and material40 is assigned

Please help me with this
enter code here

enter code here
```

Comment: If these are pivot tables (which is very unclear in your question) why are you storing this in coma seperated values?

Comment: These are not pivot tables.

Comment: Okay, so why not make a relationship?